# Login Issue - After User Table Updation

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am new in Laravel, So please advice me the best. Thanks in advance.

User only need to provide Name, email ID and password for registering a new account in my website. So i am using a update profile form to complete the personal information after he successfully registered in to the system.

Login will works fine till the user updates his profile (using the form mentioned above). But showing a U/P mismatch error when i a user trying to login after he successfully updating his profile. Update the profile means: Updating the email, password and personal info.

I am using the table for storing the user profile details and U/P.

Is it something related to password token?

**EDIT**

After some experiments I realized that login will works fine if I am not going to update the password column. That means updating the user table except the password column.

Comment: Did you add any additional column in same table ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer I just added some more information to the question

Comment: You said everything works fine if the user doesnt update his/her password on the edit profile page. Are you sure that if the user updates their password this password gets hashed? Maybe if we can see some code we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bcrypt the input password before saving it to the database

```
$user->password = bcrypt('MyNewPassword');
$user->save()
```

(It will work if you didn't modify Laravel to use another crypt alghorithm)